# lightly alter a hash programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x

At the moment I frequently have to do something in unittests with hashes and cryptographic signatures. Sometimes they get generated, and I just need to alter one slightly and prove that something no longer works. They are strings of hex-digits 0-9 and a-f of specific length. Here is a sample 64 long:

```
h = '702b31faad0246cc89a5dc782cdf5235a885d0f529fb30a4e1e70e00938df91a'
```

I want to change just one character somewhere in there.

You can't be sure that every digit 0 - 9 and a - f will be in there, although would guess it's at least 95% certain that they all are. If you could be sure, I would just run `h = h.replace('a', 'b', 1)` on it.

If you do it manually, you can just look at it and see the third digit is 2 and run:

```
new = list(h)
new[2] = '3'
h = ''.join(new)
```

But if you cannot see it and it needs to happen programmatically, what is a clean and certain way to change just one character in it somewhere?

Comment: How is the third digit relevant?

Comment: Change just one character. Third is irrelevant. It could have been the first, the tenth, the fifteenth, but importantly just one of them.

Comment: new[2] = '3' does excactly what you want. it replaces the character at position 2 with a 3. Does not care about the symbol. You should check wether new[2] == '3' tho and replace it with something else if thats the case

Comment: Yes, but that is because I am looking at it and doing it manually. What if a random hash was created in a program, there was no person there to look at it and say that the third digit is a 2 and then replace it with something else..

Comment: @cardamom Can you see the character you are changing? Because you can just choose a random index, get the character value, and then replace that index with say the next character in the valid list.

Comment: `(set(h) - set(h[0])).pop() + h[1:]` is the shortest code I can think of, it fails only in the overwhelmingly unlikely case that all digits in the hash are the same.

Comment: Oh, yes @absolutelydevastated that would do it... just to code it in a non-clumsy manner..

Comment: `new[2] = 'a' if new[2] == '3' else 'b'` this way you make sure that you are changing to a character that it does not already have.

Comment: @cardamom if you found your answer, can you mark one as accepted ?

Comment: @GrégoireRoussel am testing the latest ones received, will do that just not immediately..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```python
from random import randrange
h = '702b31faad0246cc89a5dc782cdf5235a885d0f529fb30a4e1e70e00938df91a'
i = randrange(len(h))
new_h = h[:i] + hex(int(h[i], 16) + randrange(1, 16))[-1:] + h[i+1:]
```

In words:

- choose a random index `i` in `h`
- split the string into the part before the index, the char at the index, and the rest
- replace the char at the index with its hex value incremented by a random int between 1 and 15, modulo 16 (i.e., its rightmost hex character)
- build the new string from the above pieces

Note that an increment by a value between 1 and 15 (included), followed by a modulo 16, never maps a hex digit onto itself. An increment by 0 or 16 would map it exactly onto itself.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you increment the last character of the hash (cycling to 0 after `f`). That way you are sure to get a different hash, only differing by one character.

You can easily extend this method to change a character at the position of your choosing, and not just the last one.

```py
h = '702b31faad0246cc89a5dc782cdf5235a885d0f529fb30a4e1e70e00938df91a'

def change_hash(h, index=-1):
    digits = list(h)
    old_digit= digits[index]
    v = int(old_digit, 16)
    new_v = (v+1)%16
    new_digit = '{:x}'.format(new_v)
    digits[index] = new_digit
    return ''.join(digits)

print(change_hash(h))
# 702b31faad0246cc89a5dc782cdf5235a885d0f529fb30a4e1e70e00938df91b
#                                                                ^
print(change_hash(h, 2))
# 703b31faad0246cc89a5dc782cdf5235a885d0f529fb30a4e1e70e00938df91a
#   ^
```

**EDIT**:

- added option to change a digit at an arbitrary position
- formatting the digit using `format()` as it was proposed in another answer

Answer (score 2):

You can just choose a random index

```
import random

valid_chars = '0...f'

def replace_hash(hash_digest):
    idx_to_replace = random.randint(64)
    char_to_replace = hash_digest[idx_to_replace]
    replacements = valid_chars.replace(char_to_replace, '')
    hash_digest[idx_to_replace] = replacements[random.randint(15)
    return hash_digest
```

The most efficient way is to just replace the first char with 1 of 2 replacements. I mean, you can only collide with one char anyway so there's no need to do it randomly. But if you want a random change the function'll work.

Answer (score 1):

```
h = chr(ord(h[0]) + ((-1) if (h[0] in "9z") else 1)) + h[1:]
```